# Combinations of doors and key rings

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

I've been lurking here for some years, and now finally came up with a combinatorial question to ask. :-)

A company produces doors with three separate locks. Each lock has a unique key, but similar locks can be installed in several doors. However, they only produce 28 different types of locks in total. Additionally, a key ring from them will have exactly three different keys (which I guess is some security dictate).

Q: What is the minimum number of doors I could order so that no single key ring could open them all? How about two separate key rings?

A: Four. For any set of three doors we could just pick a key that opens it and combine these into one key ring.

Similarly, for any set of six doors, two key rings would suffice, but not necessarily for seven doors. Crucially, these seven doors could have 21 different locks from the available set of 28.

Actual Question: What is a minimum number of doors such that no set of three key rings could open them all?

Any combination of 27 locks on three doors can be opened with nine freely chosen keys. If we had unlimited individual locks, ten doors would be enough with a total of 30 locks to cover. However, we are limited to 28 locks so a couple of them would be repeated. This means that we could pick those keys to be on our key rings, allowing us to open more than just three doors per key ring. (Either 4+3+3 or 4+4+2.)

When we add more doors, we are also adding more locks that may already be unlockable. Where does this end? What's the trick to choosing the right locks for our doors?

I feel this might be some sort of graph coloring problem, which I can't always get my head around. Luckily, while there are ${28 \choose 3} = 3276$ different possible doors, any nine keys can only open ${28 \choose 3} - {28-9 \choose 3} = 2307$ of these, so we at least have an upper bound of 2308 doors that should do the trick. But this applies to every set of this size and feels too high as a minimum set. Can you do better?

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: (Side note: The key ring aspect seems unnecessary, other than to produce some symmetry in the problem. Then, the general question would be: Given doors with $l$ locks each, and a total of $t>l$ locks, then what's the minimum number of doors that we can't guarantee to open with $ \lfloor \frac{t}{l} \rfloor + 1 $ keys? If so, it seems likely that this has an answer in the literature, but I'm not familiar enough with it.)